# SurveyMonkey Popup form not appearing in Chrome, FireFox, or Safari but appears in IE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, surveymonkey

I have a Sitecore 7 site that has a SurveyMonkey popup invitation form embedded on a subpage. I noticed that in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari that the form isn't automatically appearing when I visit that particular page. If I leave the page and came back (like literally hit the back button in the browser) then the form would appear. I don't see any errors in the dev console to indicate anything may be wrong.

The odd thing is that the form appears automatically on the subpage if I'm in IE--no problems at all.

I tried looking around on Survey Monkey for any troubleshooting tips but couldn't find anything related to this issue, nor could I find anything in a Google search that was helpful.

Has anyone experienced this with Survey Monkey before? This is very frustrating as I can't see any reason why the popup would not be working consistently in 3 major browsers.

For reference, here is the embed code:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" Inherits="Layouts.Testproductdetails.TestproductdetailsSublayout" CodeFile="~/layouts/Test/testProductDetails.ascx.cs" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>
    <div class="subpage-subheading">Redacted</div> 
    <div class="subpage-header Item-No">
        <sc:Text runat="server" ID="ProductNO" />
    </div>
    <div class="subpage-product-right-mobile clearfix">
        <sc:Image runat="server" ID="FullSizeImage" CssClass="ProductTypeImage" />
        <div class="subpage-product-right-img-lbl-mobile">
             <sc:Text runat="server" ID="ProductNoSmallMobile" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage-left-content-block">
        <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Description" />
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Visible="false" ID="ShopOnline" target="_blank" class="Shop-Btn">
            Shop Online
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <a  href="#" class="buttonType1 RequestInfo Req-Info-Btn">Request Info</a>
    </div>
    <div class="subpage-product-right">
        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="ProductImage" runat="server" CssClass="categoryImage" />
        <div class="subpage-product-right-img-lbl">
            <sc:Text runat="server" ID="ProductNoSmall" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-detail-divider"></div>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Downloads" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        (function ($) {
            $(function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#ShowLargeImage").fancybox();

                    $("#viewMoreCompats").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#ExtraCompatibleDevices").toggle("slow");
                        if ($("#viewMoreCompats").html() == "View More +") {
                            $("#viewMoreCompats").html("View Less -");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#viewMoreCompats").html("View More +");
                        }

                        $(".productDetailSection img").each(function () {
                            var img = $(this);
                            if (img.width() > 140) {
                                img.css({ 'width': '140px' });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#viewMoreCompats2").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#ExtraCompatibleDevices2").toggle("slow");
                        if ($("#viewMoreCompats2").html() == "View More +") {
                            $("#viewMoreCompats2").html("View Less -");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#viewMoreCompats2").html("View More +");
                        }

                        $(".productDetailSection img").each(function () {
                            var img = $(this);
                            if (img.width() > 140) {
                                img.css({ 'width': '140px' });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#viewMoreAccessories").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#ExtraAccessories").toggle("slow");
                        if ($("#viewMoreAccessories").html() == "View More +") {
                            $("#viewMoreAccessories").html("View Less -");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#viewMoreAccessories").html("View More +");
                        }

                        $(".productDetailSection img").each(function () {
                            var img = $(this);
                            if (img.width() > 140) {
                                img.css({ 'width': '140px' });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#viewMoreAccessories2").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#ExtraAccessories2").toggle("slow");
                        if ($("#viewMoreAccessories2").html() == "View More +") {
                            $("#viewMoreAccessories2").html("View Less -");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#viewMoreAccessories2").html("View More +");
                        }

                        $(".productDetailSection img").each(function () {
                            var img = $(this);
                            if (img.width() > 140) {
                                img.css({ 'width': '140px' });
                            }
                        });

                    });

                    $("#tab1").fancybox({
                        //'title': $("#tab1").html()
                    });
                    $("#tab2").fancybox({
                        //'title': $("#tab2").html()
                    });

                    $(".productDetailSection img").each(function () {
                        var img = $(this);
                        if (img.width() > 140) {
                            img.css({ 'width': '140px' });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <div class="TABLE-CONTAINER clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="product-detail-header-row clearfix">
            <div class="product-specs-header">
                product specifications:<br>
            </div>
            <div id="tabbedLinks">
                <div class="product-tbl-link">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tab2" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-tbl-link">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tab1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="attributes" />

    </div>

        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CompatibleProducts" />

        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="CompatibleProducts2" /> 

        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Accessories" />

        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Accessories2" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        (function ($) {
            $(function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // Request Info
                    $('.RequestInfo').click(function (event) {
                        var url = "/Redacted/otherpages/requestinformation.aspx?In Reference To=Item: " + $(".Item-No").html().trim();

                            var width = 735;
                            var height = 710;

                            $.fancybox({
                                'title': 'Request Information',
                                'autoDimensions': false,
                                'width': width,
                                'height': height,
                                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                                'href': url,
                            });

                        event.preventDefault();

                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>


    <asp:Literal ID="DownloadScript" runat="server" />

    <div class="productDetailSection">
        <div id="contentTab1" style="display: none" class="noPrint">
            <div class="show">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Tab1Content"></asp:Literal></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentTab2" style="display: none" class="noPrint">
            <div class="show">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Tab2Content"></asp:Literal></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--Survey Code -->

    <sc:Placeholder runat="server" Key="SurveyCode"></sc:Placeholder>
```

Comment: Have checked to see if your popup blocker is on?  Sounds awfully simple but sometimes those are the answers we miss.

Comment: I also wonder where you have your script tag on the screen. It very well could be that you're loading the script tag after some error, why you see it when you return and not on init visit

Comment: @DylanWright I added the code for the Sitecore file that has the survey script in it. It's at the very bottom. Something to note: this site was created by another developer and there are a lot of poorly written code.

Enabling popups does not seem to fix the issue :\

Comment: Well you could eliminate other code by separating it from other code. Looks like a lot of code just throw up a survey too.  My bet would be on that other code you mentioned.  Pull up your dev tools see if it hits the breakpoint that triggers your survey.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right with the SurveyMonkey embed code. On a whim, I put it on pages for 2 different sites (both SilverStripe sites) and have the exact same issues. It can't be a coincidence. I think I need to get access to the SurveryMonkey account the form came from so I can inspect the setup.